# roots with negative real parts

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Under what constraints on the parameters a,b, and c does the transcendental equation

$$x+a+be^{-x}+ce^{-kx}=0$$  ($k$ is a constant)
have ALL its roots with negative real parts? Alternatively, any good references to this type of problem are most welcome.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for math.SE. It also doesn't look like complex analysis to me. Is $k>0$? I would start by reducing the four-dimensional space to a three-dimensional one with the substitution $x\rightarrow x-a$, which brings the equation into the form $x+pe^{-x}+qe^{-kx}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain a little bit how you arrived at your result? I'm assuming you employed Rouch\'{e}'s theorem or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

One sufficient condition is that $k > 0$ and  $\text{Re}(a) - |b| - |c| > 0$.